# Not storing two date fields in a single model

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I am newbie to the `Yii Framework`.I have a `model called invoice`.In that model the attributes are like
`invoice_title,invoice_issue_date,due_date,description`.
Now my problem is that as my models have both invoice_issue_date and due_date are date fields,but only one is storing the dates and the other one is just storing it like `0000-00-00`.Here is the code for my model.

```
<?php

/**
 * This is the model class for table "{{invoices}}".
 *
 * The followings are the available columns in table '{{invoices}}':
 * @property integer $id
 * @property integer $customer_id
 * @property integer $payment_id
 * @property string $invoice_title
 * @property string $invoice_issue_date
 * @property string $due_date
 * @property string $description
 */
class Invoices extends CActiveRecord
{
  /**
   * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
   * @param string $className active record class name.
   * @return Invoices the static model class
   */
  public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
  {
    return parent::model($className);
  }

  /**
   * @return string the associated database table name
   */
  public function tableName()
  {
    return '{{invoices}}';
  }

  /**
   * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
   */
  public function rules()
  {
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
      array('invoice_title, invoice_issue_date,due_date', 'required'),
      array('invoice_title','length','min'=>6),
      array('invoice_title,description', 'length', 'max'=>120),
      // The following rule is used by search().
      // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
      array('id, invoice_title, invoice_issue_date, due_date, description', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );

  }

  /**
   * @return array relational rules.
   */
  public function relations()
  {
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(

    );
  }

  protected function afterFind(){
    parent::afterFind();
    $this->due_date=date('d F, Y', strtotime(str_replace("-", "", $this->due_date)));
  }

  protected function beforeSave(){
    if(parent::beforeSave()){
        $this->due_date=date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace(",", "", $this->due_date)));
        return TRUE;
    }
    else return false;
  }



  /**
   * @return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
   */
  public function attributeLabels()
  {
    return array(
      'id' => 'ID',
      'invoice_title' => 'Invoice Title',
      'invoice_issue_date' => 'Invoice Issue Date',
      'due_date' => 'Due Date',
      'description' => 'Description',
    );
  }

  /**
   * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
   * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models based on the search/filter conditions.
   */
  public function search()
  {
    // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
    // should not be searched.

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
    $criteria->compare('invoice_title',$this->invoice_title,true);
    $criteria->compare('invoice_issue_date',$this->invoice_issue_date,true);
    $criteria->compare('due_date',$this->due_date,true);
    $criteria->compare('description',$this->description,true);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
      'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
  }
}
```

The code for view file

```
<div class="form">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
  'id'=>'invoices-form',
  'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
)); ?>

  <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

  <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

  <div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'invoice_title'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'invoice_title',array('size'=>45,'maxlength'=>45)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'invoice_title'); ?>
  </div>

    <div class="row">
      <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'invoice_issue_date'); ?>
      <?php 
      $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker',
      array(
            'attribute'=>'invoice_issue_date',
            'model'=>$model,
            'options' => array(
                              'mode'=>'focus',
                              'dateFormat'=>'d MM, yy',
                              'showAnim' => 'slideDown',
                              ),
      'htmlOptions'=>array('size'=>30,'class'=>'date'),
          )
      );
      ?>
      <?php echo $form->error($model,'invoice_issue_date'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'due_date'); ?>
      <?php 
      $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker',
      array(
            'attribute'=>'due_date',
            'model'=>$model,
            'options' => array(
                              'mode'=>'focus',
                              'dateFormat'=>'d MM, yy',
                              'showAnim' => 'slideDown',
                              ),
      'htmlOptions'=>array('size'=>30,'class'=>'date'),
          )
      );
      ?>
      <?php echo $form->error($model,'due_date'); ?>
    </div>

  <div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'description'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textArea($model,'description',array('rows'=>6, 'cols'=>50)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'description'); ?>
  </div>

  <div class="row buttons">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
  </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div><!-- form -->
```

Comment: post the code that actually uses this model to insert data into the database? 0000-00-00 might be defined as the default value in your DB schema. so when you don't pass it the right value it uses the default.

Comment: can you please clarify what exactly is the problem?

Comment: when I am going to store the dates entered in the  invoice_issue_date and due_date, only due_date is storing the date values and in invoice_issue_date field it is storing only 0000-00-00.

Comment: tell me exactly what are your **db** data types(or formats) for both invoice_issue_date and due_date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my model I made changes for `afterFind()` and `beforeSave()` like this

```
  protected function afterFind(){
    parent::afterFind();
    $this->due_date=date('d F, Y', strtotime(str_replace("-", "", $this->due_date)));
    $this->invoice_issue_date=date('d F, Y', strtotime(str_replace("-", "", $this->invoice_issue_date)));
  }

  protected function beforeSave(){
    if(parent::beforeSave()){
        $this->due_date=date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace(",", "", $this->due_date)));
        $this->invoice_issue_date=date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace(",", "", $this->invoice_issue_date)));
        return TRUE;
    }
    else return false;
  }
```

and in view file {{ _form }}. I made it like this

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'invoice_issue_date'); ?>
    <?php 
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker',
      array(
        'attribute'=>'invoice_issue_date',
        'model'=>$model,
        'options' => array(
                      'mode'=>'focus',
                      'dateFormat'=>'d MM, yy',
                      'showAnim' => 'slideDown',
                      ),
        'htmlOptions'=>array('size'=>30,'class'=>'date', 'value'=>date("d F, Y")),
        )
      );      
     ?>
   <?php echo $form->error($model,'invoice_issue_date'); ?>
    </div>

<div class="row">
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'due_date'); ?>
<?php 
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker',
array(
      'attribute'=>'due_date',
      'model'=>$model,
      'options' => array(
                        'mode'=>'focus',
                        'dateFormat'=>'d MM, yy',
                        'showAnim' => 'slideDown',
                        ),
'htmlOptions'=>array('size'=>30,'class'=>'date'),
    )
);
?>
<?php echo $form->error($model,'due_date'); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common mistake at starting with yii :P Add 'dueDate' to your rules array:

```
array('dueDate', 'safe'),
```

Comment: I have used due_date @ `array('invoice_title, invoice_issue_date,due_date', 'required'),`
but still it is not storing the invoice_issue_date

Comment: Ok. You're trying to set the due_date value on the 'beforeSave' function. There you call the beforeSave parent function, but in th CActiveRecord definition, it doesn't return a boolean value, so your code there is useless :S Try to remove the condition and leave only the setting code for 'due_date'.

Comment: For 'invoice_issue_date' it would help to see the view code where it gets values.

Comment: sucotronic, parent beforeSave does return a boolean value, check [the documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#beforeSave-detail)

Comment: With the view code now is easy to see the fail. If you look at mysql doc, it says 'Invalid DATE, DATETIME, or TIMESTAMP values are converted to the “zero” value of the appropriate type ('0000-00-00' or '0000-00-00 00:00:00').', so the problem is the format of the date. Try to put this format: dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"  it should work ok. If you prefer other format, be sure to transform it before assign it to the model and save in the db :)

Answer (score 0):

in `afterFind` and `beforeSave` you are re-formatting the due_date value but not the `invoice_issue_date` value.
In `beforeSave` You have to make sure all values are in a valid timestamp format the database can handle.
So if it is not `YYYY-MM-DD` database will likely save `0000-00-00` instead.

Comment: cebe have you read the documentation? according to me parent beforeSave will return boolean, am i missing something? because i commented on sucotronic's answer also, about the parent::beforeSave

Comment: yep, you are right. Thougt about beforeFind when writing this. removed it.

Comment: In the database, yes, but what is their value in beforeSave?